Digest calculation for xml enveloped signature in Java
I have to generate Enveloped XML Signature. I have tried using javax.xml.crypto.dsig and org.apache.xml.security, but unfortunately web service does not accept my request due to wrong signature. By tutorial given example, I'm trying to get signed xml as provided. As I see, I cannot even get the same digest for original XML.
Help me please understand, why I cannot get expected digest for this XML using CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315",
SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1",
DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrdrModify ordrModType="ACTI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <StandardHeader marketID="IM"/>
 <OrdrList>
  <Ordr ordrId="0" qty="100" revisionNo="0" type="O"/>
 </OrdrList>
</OrdrModify>

Digest value according to provided example I have to get is:
vx6g0IKv5Qw1nwqOM4hGmn5igXY=
My java code to get digest:
public static String getDigestCanon(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    try {
        Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance("http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315");
        byte[] canonXmlBytes = canon.canonicalize(data.getBytes());
        String canonXmlString = new String(canonXmlBytes);

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

        byte[] hash = digest.digest(canonXmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] encodedBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(hash);

        return new String(encodedBytes);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Main.log.error("error",e);
    }

    return "";
}

My function returns:
3z7IKwuJ5xctEvZ0l+frYcBEQdI=

byte[] canonXmlBytes = canon.canonicalize(data.getBytes()); Never do that. Always specify the encoding for getBytes. Just saying, but SHA1 is insecure. For testing, you should tell us your input.

If it's any consolation, I just got exactly the same result as you, using somewhat different methods

But, afaik, from a brief look at docs on this stuff, it looks like what is normally needful of canonicalization is the <SignedInfo> element of the document, which you don't have
